# Making the Fourier transform quantitative

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, harmonic-analysis, sobolev-spaces

I am undergraduate Physics student and understand that this is a professional mathematics forum. But due to perhaps broader interest, I hope this question is suitable for this website.

I understand the Fourier transform is a Hilbert space isometry 
$F:L^2(\mathbb R^d) \rightarrow L^2(\mathbb R^d).$

In Quantum Mechanics we are told that intuitively the Fourier transform transforms narrow signals into extended ones, I would like to make this precise.

The best example which illustrate this, is when one considers the Fourier transform on Schwartz distributions, $F(\delta_x)(k)=e^{ikx},$ but this is very unquantitative.

A good decay measure in "Fourier space" seem to be Sobolev spaces since

$$\left\lVert f \right\rVert_{H^s(\mathbb R^d)} = \left( \int_{\mathbb R^d} \left\lvert F(f) \right\rvert^2 (1+\vert x \vert^2)^{s} \ dx \right)^{1/2}$$

Let us fix a signal $f \in L^2(\mathbb R^d)$ of unit norm.

I call the signal $f$ to be $\varepsilon,\delta-$localized if there is a ball $B(x,\delta)$ such that $\left\lVert f1_{B(x,\delta)} \right\rVert_{L^2} \ge 1-\varepsilon$.

I would say that the intuitive explanation of the Fourier transform should then imply that if $f$ is in the $H^s$ Sobolev space, with $s>0$ and $\left\lVert f \right\rVert_{H^s} \le k$ then for any $\delta(k)>0$ there is $\varepsilon'(\delta(k))>0$ such that $f$ cannot be $\varepsilon'(\delta(k)),\delta(k)-$localized. 
Is this true? 
Can one find this $\varepsilon'$ explicitly?

The above question is motivated by the statement that if a function is in $H^s$ with bounded norm, then it decays sufficiently rapidly in Fourier space that it cannot be too localized in real space.

Comment: Possibly something [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Uncertainty_principle) is related to what you want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Notice that $\|f1_{B(0,\delta)}\|_{L^2}\to 0$ as $\delta\to 0$. So the answer to the question is no because it should reasonably include the requirement $\varepsilon'<1$. -- Rapid decrease of the Fourier transform $F(f)$ implies smoothness of $f$ but, without further assumptions, it does not imply localization.

Answer (score 8):

There are various mathematical formulations of this phenomenon and some of them are quite quantitative.

First, there is the classical [Heisenberg uncertainty principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Uncertainty_principle) which roughly states that the product of the variances of a functions and its Fourier transform is bounded from below, independently of the function.

Then there is the uncertainty principle of [Donoho and Stark](http://digitalassets.lib.berkeley.edu/sdtr/ucb/text/94.pdf). Its discrete form says that for every $x\in\mathbb{C}^N$ it holds that product of the number of non-zero entries in $x$ and the number of non-zero entries in its Fourier transform $\hat x$ is greater than $N$. The continuous version is a bit more complicated: Call some function $f$ *$\epsilon$-concentrated* on a set $T$ if there is some $g$ with support in $T$ such that $\|f-g\|_2\leq \epsilon$ (i.e. the $L^2$-norm of $f$ outside of $T$ is smaller than $\epsilon$). The uncertainty principle says that for $f$ and $\hat f$ with unit norm such that $f$ is $\epsilon_T$ concentrated on some set $T$ and $\hat f$ is $\epsilon_W$ concentrated on some set $W$ it holds that $$|T||W|\geq (1- \epsilon_T-\epsilon_W)^2.$$

There is much more to say, e.g. there is Lieb's uncertainty principle for the short-time-Fourier transform, there are results of "time-and-band-limiting operators" by Landau/Pollack and Slepian/Landau. I can recommend the books "Foundations of Time-Frequency Analysis" by Karlheiz Gröchenig and "Ten Lectures on Wavelets" by Ingrid Daubechies for further reading.